# Jenkins ver. 1.651.3 credential plugin doesn't want to work with git

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, credentials

When I'am trying to use my github record from credential plugin, I can't push from job and get error:

```
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured
```

[With credential](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vy1ms.png)

But if i paste my login information into url, it works perfectly.

[Paste in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXY2T.png)

How i can resolve this thing with standard credential plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good idea for this specific plugin , but I think it's about to upgrade Jenkins to `2.X` there are a lot of bug fixes that run only on `2.x`

we had some other issues and after 2-3 weeks we complete the upgrade.

good luck !!